# check 10 PlayerPrefs which is Empty and Save

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i coded the following code i want to check which PlayerPrefs is empty and save text from inputbox then display it in Ui text

```
SaveTittlesText1.text=PlayerPrefs.GetString("1");
SaveTittlesText2.text=PlayerPrefs.GetString("2");
SaveTittlesText3.text=PlayerPrefs.GetString("3")
```

problem is Uitext3 is displaying text from Uitex2 please help i want to achieve this in more than 10 PlayerPrefs

```
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("1") == false)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("1",InputsaveTittes.text.ToString());

    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
else if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("1") == true)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("2",InputsaveTittes.text.ToString());

    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
else if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("2") == false)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("2",InputsaveTittes.text.ToString());

     PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
else if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("2") == true)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("3",InputsaveTittes.text.ToString());

    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

Comment: _Just like salt on chips, code listings are always nicer when formatted properly._ ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand that use case / logic but you are skipping a case:

```
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("1") == false)
{
    // sets 1
}
else if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("1") == true) // WHAT IF IT ALSO PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("2") == true here ?
{
    // sets 2
}
else if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("2") == false) // WILL NEVER BE REACHED
{
    // sets 2
}
else if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("2") == true) // WILL NEVER BE REACHED
{
    // sets 3
}
```

your last two cases will never be reached/checked at all since your first two cases already cover all possibilities!

you should either check like e.g.

```
if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("1"))
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("1", InputsaveTittes.text);
}
// already know that 1 is set since otherwise it would have entered the first case
else if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("2")) 
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("2", InputsaveTittes.text);
}
// Any other case -> this means 1 and 2 are already set
else 
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("3", InputsaveTittes.text);
}

PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

or in general use loops!

```
// iterate over 1,2,3
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    // check if current index is already used
    if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(i))
    {
        // if not set it
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(i.ToString(), InputsaveTittes.text);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

        // skip the rest of the loop
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Actually I would however rather simply have another entry for storing the current index -  especially if you are going for more items - like e.g.

```
// defaults to 0 if there is no index yet -> first player will have index 1
var index = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("index", 0);
// increase index by 1
index++;
// store string to this new index
PlayerPrefs.SetString(index.ToString(), InputsaveTittes.text);
// also store the new index
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("index", index);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

at the same time `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("index", 0);` will now also return the amount of already saved strings.

---

> problem is Uitext3 is displaying text from Uitex2

This, however, sounds like you simply referenced the same `Text` component in both fields `SaveTittlesText2` and `SaveTittlesText3`.